# Almacenamiento de variables POST en JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un formulario de `login`, que tiene que enviar unos datos por post y almacenarlo en un `array` con el cual se trabajara para hacer consultas variadas con bases de datos (todo esto sin usar PHP). A todo esto, quería saber si javascript/JQuery puede almacenar variables POST.

En `index.html` tengo este script. Es el encargado de recoger los valores del formulario y enviarlo a la página de funciones JS.

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(ev){
    $url="funciones.js";

/* SECCION INICIO SESION */
    $('.container').on('click','#btnIniSesion', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

         var datos={
              "mail":$('#Mail').val(),
              "clave":$('#Clave').val(),
              "accion":"IniSesion"
              }
             $.ajax({
                type:"post",   //Tipo de peticion
                url:$url,    //URL pagina a cargar
                data:datos,    //Datos a pasar a pagina PHP
                success: function(data){
                 $('#container').html(data);

                }
             });
        });
 /* FIN SECCION INI_SESION */      
});
```

Y aquí está el formulario html que se encuentra dentro del mismo fichero:

```
<form role="form">
     <fieldset>
         <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" id='Mail' autofocus>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" id='Clave'value="">
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                  <input name="remember" type="checkbox">Recuerdame
              </label>
         </div>
         <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnIniSesion">Login</button>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

No he escrito nada más, ya que no puedo ponerme a crear las funciones javascript sin saber si es posible esa recepción de los datos del formulario sin hacer uso de PHP.

Comment: Buenas @AntonioMP87, ¿podrías editar el post y poner el código que estás desarrollando para realizar esa acción?
Así sería más fácil analizarlo ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias almacenar las variables en la cookie del navegador, es lo que se suele hacer cuando estas desarrollando sin base de datos (PHP).

Te recomiendo esta libreria: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Como vas a enviar las variables al servidor sin PHP? No creo que te haga falta guardar de tipo POST la variable, tu las guardas y luego le dices en la comunicacion como sera la comunicacion.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has dado otro punto de vista para abordar el asunto. Usare la sugerencia que me has dado.

Comment: Para eso estamos :) cualquier cosa nos dices, y te puedo ayudar con el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer es consumir una API que es muy diferente a no utilizar PHP. Con javascript puedes hacer peticiones del tipo AJAX como lo expones en tu ejemplo y si puedes enviar cualquier dato que necesites
Como ejemplo para enviar data en una petición POST puedes ocupar algo así

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript es lenguage de cliente, no puedes hacer consultas a la base de datos con él. Tienes que usar el lenguage de servidor que tengas. En este caso hablas de PHP.

Para la próxima intenta dar más detalles, como partes de tu código. ;)

Comment: Todo el motor de base de datos esta manejado con otro leguaje y yo, a traves de javascript, tengo que interacturar con la API y que la API se comunique con la base de datos. De ahi, saber si es posible el envio de datos por post usando solamente javascript o jquery.

Comment: Es posible con una consulta ajax como la tienes hecha arriba, pero depende del archivo que se conecte con la db. 
 Si el tuyo va con una API deberías leer bien la documentación de la API y saber si necesita una llamada Ajax, Curl, o lo que te pida.