# enviar datos a traves de AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

¿por qué no pasan las variables de `ajax` a `php`?

Éste es el script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#editarot_btn").click(function(){

        var ot_antigua = $("#ot_editar").val();
        var ot_nueva = $("#nueva_ot").val();
        var cuenta = $("#cuenta").val();

        alert(ot_antigua + "-" + ot_nueva + "-" + cuenta);

        var dataString = 'ot_antigua=' + ot_antigua + '&ot_nueva=' + ot_nueva + '&cuenta=' + cuenta;


var saveme = $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "editar_ot.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType:"html",
                asycn:false,
                success: function(){
                   alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
                }
        }).responseText;

        console.log(saveme);

    });

});
```

Éste es el código php que recibe:

```
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['user'];

require('connect_db.php');

$ot_antigua=$_POST['ot_antigua'];
$ot_nueva=$_POST['ot_nueva'];
$cuenta=$_POST['cuenta'];

//print_r($_POST);

print($ot_antigua.'= ot antigua<br>'); 
print($ot_nueva.'= ot nueva<br>');
print($cuenta.'= cuenta');
```

Comment: estas enviando un string y no unos parametro por post un ejemplo de uso https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/62463/28035

Comment: Hacer peticiones de forma síncrona como las tienes se considera una mala práctica porque da una mala experiencia de usuario (el navegador permanecerá bloqueado mientras dure la petición). Deberías evitarlas

Answer (score 1):

Debe ser por que estás diciendo que el metodo es POST y las envías como GET, prueba enviándolas así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editarot_btn").click(function(){
        var ot_antigua = $("#ot_editar").val();
        var ot_nueva = $("#nueva_ot").val();
        var cuenta = $("#cuenta").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "editar_ot.php",
            data: {ot_antigua:ot_antigua, ot_nueva:ot_nueva, cuenta:cuenta},
            success: function(){
                alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Los parámetros se pueden pasar como un objeto o como un string y eso no afecta al método especificado en el ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Trata esto,

solo quite unas cositas que tenias en el codigo, intenta hacerto y revisa bien si la ruta donde se encuentra tu codigo php esta correcto

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#editarot_btn").click(function(){

        var ot_antigua = $("#ot_editar").val();
        var ot_nueva = $("#nueva_ot").val();
        var cuenta = $("#cuenta").val();

         var dataString = 'ot_antigua='+ot_antigua+'&ot_nueva='+ot_nueva+'&cuenta='+cuenta;

          $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "guardar.php",
                      data: dataString,
                      success: function() {

                          alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
                          alert(data); //recuperando las variables

                      }

                  });
    });
});
```

## Codigo php

```
session_start()

#imprimimos las variables que estas enviando para saber si estan llegando completas

    echo $ot_antigua=$_POST['ot_antigua'];
    echo $ot_nueva=$_POST['ot_nueva'];
    echo $cuenta=$_POST['cuenta'];
```

Comment: Hola gama984, ¿qué cositas cambiaste? ¿Y cuál fue el motivo de cambiarlas? Tal y como está redactada esta respuesta, no se puede entender cuál era el problema o cómo lo solucionaste. Trata de editarla para especificar más la solución. Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Creo que seria algo lógico que compare su código con el mio y listo, ahí estarán las cositas que cambie, saludos.

Comment: @gama84 las preguntas que son básicamente código sin una explicación de qué se hizo o por qué los cambios solucionan el problema se consideran de baja calidad. Esto es porque cuando respondes, esa respuesta no sólo la ve la persona que pregunta, sino también usuarios futuros que pueden tener un problema similar con diferente código. Una explicación (por breve que sea) sería de gran ayuda para ellos. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos, muchas gracias por prestar de su tiempo y responder. Ya encontré el error y era error de una palabra reservada de AJAX. Muchas gracias y qué pena la molestia!

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("#editarot_btn").click(function(){

        var ot_antigua = $("#ot_editar").val();
        var ot_nueva = $("#nueva_ot").val();
        var cuenta = $("#cuenta").val();

var saveme = $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "editar_ot.php",
                data:'ot_antigua=' + ot_antigua + '&ot_nueva=' + ot_nueva + '&cuenta=' + cuenta,
                dataType:"html",
                asycn:false, //el error que cometí de sintaxis, es async
                success: function(){
                   alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
                }
        })responseText;

        console.log(saveme);

    });

});
```